# Number a bunch of files in a serial order with number as prefix

Tags: rename, file-management

So, I've got 58 files on a Linux machine, with the sort of filenames given below:

```
Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Basics of TOC ｜ Lec 1 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [7DOPjYGtnTQ].mp4
Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Operations ｜ Lec 2 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [XCm43gyfl4M].mp4
Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Chomsky Hierarchy ｜ Lec 3 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [_YvKlbKmbNg].mp4
```

Every filename has "Lec" followed the lecture number in its filename. I'd like to  prepend number serially on each of the file in the following manner:

```
1 - Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Basics of TOC ｜ Lec 1 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [7DOPjYGtnTQ].mp4
2 - Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Operations ｜ Lec 2 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [XCm43gyfl4M].mp4
3 - Theory of Computation (TOC) ｜ Chomsky Hierarchy ｜ Lec 3 ｜ GATE Computer Science⧸IT Engineering Exam [_YvKlbKmbNg].mp4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which Linux are you using? Do you have a `rename` or `perl-rename` command? What is the output of `rename --version`?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '*｜ Lec (<->) ｜*' '$1 - $f'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [rename](/questions/tagged/rename):

```
rename -n 's/\bLec\s+(\d+)/$1 - $_/' Theory*
```

Remove the -n (`dry-run`) if the output looks good.

The `rename` version you need:

```
$ rename 2>&1 | grep perl
[ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```